# What happens to tasks/cases in MS Dynamics CRM that were assigned to employees that have been terminated or left the company?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I just started at a company that uses MS Dynamics CRM 2016 extensively and I've been trying to run down a comprehensive answer for how the system handles tasks/cases that have been assigned to employees within my company after those employees have left the company.

It's apparently quite a large problem because the tasks/cases have been explained to me as "falling into the void" and being unfindable once the owner (ex-employee) no longer has access. Is this true?

Is there a way to confidently query all tasks/cases for employees that no longer have access if I 1) don't have a good idea of who those employees might be and 2) don't have a full list of what might have been assigned to them?

I'm still very new to MS Dynamics CRM and am not even sure where to start. I know it's possible to run queries, advanced finds, and searches. Those in my company that have explained to me the situation seem to have tried some form of these methods so far.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Those user records should be inactivated, so you should be able to query tasks/cases with condition that the owner Status is Disabled.

Comment: Thank you! Will it be possible to reassign these or would that require some administrative privileges?

Comment: You can first query out those records in Advance find, then export those data including the owner field, change the owner field and import back.
Administrative privilege is not necessary but better to have so you would not get privilege errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prepare the list of CRM users who left the company (if not query the disabled users and identify them), then do a house keeping by reassigning their records by going to their user profile. [Read more](https://d365demystified.com/2018/11/15/d365-quick-tip-why-should-you-reassign-records-to-another-user/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll bring this up at the next roundtable.